# Are static members of generic classes shared between types

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, static

I'm trying to create a generic class which will have some static functions based on the type.  Are there static members for each type?  Or only where there is a generic used?  The reason I ask is I want a lock object for each type, not one shared between them.

So if I had

```
class MyClass<T> where T:class
{
    static object LockObj = new object();
    static List<T> ObjList = new List<T>();
}
```

I understand that ObjList would definitely have a different object created for each generic type used, but would the LockObj be different between each generic instantiation (`MyClass<RefTypeA>` and `MyClass<RefTypeB>`) or the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just check for yourself!

```
public class Static<T>
{
    public static int Number { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Static<int>.Number = 1;
    Static<double>.Number = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(Static<int>.Number + "," + Static<double>.Number);
}
// Prints 1, 2
```

Comment: I was worried about corner cases.  Still you tdd guys seem to have your heads in the right spot

Comment: @tzaman can you explain this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048279/protected-static-string-accessability-issue-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment57871825_35048279

Answer (score 7):

It will be different for each T. Basically, for all different T you will have different type and members are not shared between different types.

Answer (score 4):

Instantiated generic types in C# are actually different types at runtime, hence the static members will not be shared.

Comment: I was worried because my understanding was that each value type got a different set of code but reference types used the same "generic" set of code with a different type constraint.  Just checking for corner cases.