# Are static members of a generic class different for different types in Java?

Tags: java, generics, static

@Spence asked this [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438032/are-static-members-of-generic-classes-shared-between-types).

So, how's that work in Java?  Generic types are discarded at runtime in Java, so what happens to static variables of classes instantiated with different generic types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static members in Java can't have generic type arguments from the class that contains them.

```
public class Gen<T> {
  public static T foo; // compiler error
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Static variables are shared among all the instances of that type, even of different type parameters.

From the [generics tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf), page 14:

> As consequence, the static variables
>   and methods of a class are also shared
>   among all the instances. That is why
>   it is illegal to refer to the type
>   parameters of a type declaration in a
>   static method or initializer, or in
>   the declaration or initializer of a
>   static variable.