# protected static string accessability issue in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract base class which is a templated.

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : new()
{
     protected static string MAGIC;
}
```

I then have a two classes which derive from `Base`, but with different values of `T`.

```
public class Derived1:Base<Other1> {}

public class Derived2:Base<Other2> {}
```

Two odd things seem to be happening. First of all, `Derived2.MAGIC` is available from within a member function of `Derived1`; I would not expect that. Additionally, `Derived2` has a static constructor which sets `MAGIC`; the odd part being that `Derived2`'s static constructor is not called when `Derived1` accesses `Derived2.MAGIC` (which shouldn't even be allowed).

Two questions:

- Why can `Derived1` access a protected static member of `Derived2`?
- I thought static constructors were run before any static members were accessed, why when I access `Derived2.MAGIC`, am I not seeing it's static constructor called?

Both of these seem to be serious bugs.

Just adding a note that if MAGIC was on the other hand a static protected function, this problem does not exist, which makes the whole thing even more unclear.

Comment: I suspect that root of this question is assuming that concrete types of a generic type have some relation to each other (i.e. `Base<Other1>` and `Base<Other2>` have some imaginary parent class that they both derive from like `ImaginaryBase<*>`) which is not the case at all in C# - they are just regular types (deriving from `Object` in this case) and no have no other special relation to each other.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I was assuming the opposite, that the bases are completely unrelated, but apparently they are because a class which derives from Base<Other1> can access Derived2.MAGIC. There is definitely something odd about generics and static members.

Comment: I read question so wrong ... Consider adding method to your post that shows what causes confusion (the fact that all instances of `Base<T>.MAGIC` is available to all derived classes is indeed surprising).

Answer (score 7):

> Why can `Derived1` access a protected static member of `Derived2`?

`MAGIC` is in a common base class, not in `Derived2`. Any subclass of `Base<T>` will see a variable of the same name, though it will actually be different variables if `T` is different for each derived class.

> I thought static constructors were run before any static members were accessed, why when I access `Derived2.MAGIC`, am I not seeing it's static constructor called?

There is no declaration `Derived2.MAGIC`, there is a declaration `Base<T>.MAGIC`. `Derived1` is accessing a protected field declared in its own base class.

You are starting from an assumption that MAGIC is declared in `Derived2`. If you change your code so that's actually the case, your expectations will hold.

Comment: Technically, isn't `Derived2.MAGIC` the same as `Base<Other2>.MAGIC` since generic types have different static instances based on the generic parameter(s)? IOW `Derived2.MAGIC` and `Derived1.MAGIC` are different static variables?

Comment: @DStanley precisely.  If you had `Derived3 : Base<Other2>` its MAGIC field would be the same as the Derived2 MAGIC field.  But Derived1's MAGIC field is different, because it is a field of `Base<Other1>`.

Comment: MAGIC is not in a common base class otherwise Base<Other1> and Base<Other2> would have a shared MAGIC, which they don't. If Base<Other1> and Base<Other2> both derived from the same Base, then there would only be one copy of MAGIC, which there isn't.

Comment: @bpeikes: That is correct in terms of the compile type types, but it is declared in a class from which both concrete subclasses derive. I did explain what you state in my answer, but I don't know the correct term for this situation. Do you? If so feel free to add a comment or just edit the answer.

Comment: @EricJ. This is generics not inheritance. By following your logic, Base<Other1> and Base<Other2> both derive from Base<T>, except there is no such thing as Base<T>. Additionally, Base<Other1>.MAGIC and Base<Other2>.MAGIC, have different storage, so MAGIC can't be in some Base<T> class, it's in the concrete Base<Other1> or Base<Other2>.

Answer (score 1):

Though Eric J has already explained thoroughly, I'd like to add a note that one reason it may seem like there are two values for `MAGIC` is because there are - `static` members in generic classes behave with a little bit of magic in that there'll be a different field for each generic overload, ie `Base<Other1>.MAGIC` and `Base<Other2>.MAGIC`. The inheriting behaviour may be more obvious if you tried this same example with a nongeneric `Base`, in which case you will see `MAGIC` only exists once and changes from either derived classes will affect the same field.

Comment: I assumed that there are two separate statics, which clearly there are, but it still makes no sense that Derived1 can access Derived2.MAGIC. Derived2.MAGIC should, because it's protected, only be accessable from anything that is derived from Base<Other2>, not from Base<Other1>